# Digital voltage/current controller for DIY bench power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, current-limiting, constant-current

I'm trying to design a portable rechargeable bench power supply.  I have a 12V sealed lead-acid battery (WP7.2-12) which I can use as the main power source. These batteries are cheap and easy to source, and have reasonable power output specifications.

I would like to be able to digitally control the output voltage and current using a microcontroller.

I'm seeking advice for a voltage/current output controller which would be reasonably easy to interface with a MCU.  It needs to be digitally controlled (i.e. serial, SPI, I2C, 8-bit bus, etc), and should be able to provide two modes of operation:

1. Voltage output with selectable voltage and maximum current
   (0-12V, 0-10A)
2. Constant current output with selectable current output (0-10A)

(Maybe these features need to be implemented as two separate circuits, using relays to connect the output to one or the other...)

Would an LED driver such as those referenced [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223636/digitally-controlled-0-10a-constant-current-source-for-driving-leds) be a good route for this type of controller, or would it be best to roll-my-own circuitry for this?  Any pointers/tips appreciated.

Obviously there are other components (i.e. overcurrent protection, battery charge controller, deep-discharge prevention, user interface, etc.) that must be implemented as well, but for this question I'm simply seeking a way to control the output voltage/current per the above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find a suitable voltage regulator that can supply up to 12 volts at 10 amps and has a feedback (FB) pin that is used for setting the output voltage via a potential divider.
2. If your input voltage is only 12 volt then use a pre-boost regulator to deliver maybe 15 volts to the regulator described in (1).
3. If you consider that maybe 11.5 volts is enough at the output then you don't need a pre-regulator if your main regulator has enough grunt and low drop-out to do the job (but you won't quite get 12 volts of course).

Two more things to do and the first revolves around using a digital pot to control the voltage fed back to the FB pin. Alternatively inject a current into the FB node that can "con" the regulator into assuming a diufferent voltage output. Here's the first idea: -

[image]

This was taken from figure 8 in [this ADI document](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/tutorials/MT-091.pdf).

The second idea is to use this type of injection using a current output DAC: -

[image]

Or like this: -

[image]

And the second thing to do is have a small resistor in series with the output of the regulator (but before the feedback resistors) that can be used to measure load current. You can use a circuit like this that takes the high-side measurement and references it to 0 volts that can be read by an ADC: -

[image]

The above taken from [here](http://www.electronicdesign.com/analog/calculating-accuracy-high-side-current-sense-amplifiers).

Or you go the [whole-hog](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/whole-hog) and get yourself a step-Down controller with Digital Power System Management like the [LTC3886](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3886): -

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the detail.  The LTC3886 looks like a very capable chip - it might be the way for me to go. Might even give the capability for more features that I wasn't planning originally. :)

Comment: I think you might only be able to control it down to 0.5 volts so watch out for that.

Comment: @Andyaka - Thanks for the _very_ detailed reply. As I said, im new to electronics but I want to learn and I will try some of this. I think I saw before that you weren't sure where to add the resistance/current control to manage the speed. It looks like it's between the C and T pins. You can see what I mean here when this guy uses a manual speed board for the same type of controller https://youtu.be/W_Ug0JtW3q8?t=40

Comment: @Justin I'm not sure what you refer to when you say this: *I think I saw before that you weren't sure where to add the resistance/current control to manage the speed. It looks like it's between the C and T pins* <-- so please be more direct. I don't see the relevance of the video link either.

Answer (score 1):

Something that the other answer doesn't address:

> 1. Voltage output with selectable voltage and maximum current (0-12V, 0-10A)
> 2. Constant current output with selectable current output (0-10A)

Those are the same thing. The "current only" operation mode means you set the voltage to a maximum value, and the current is regulated.

If you wanted one of those made in a couple of hours:

1. Buy a 200W car inverter with 120V output.
2. Buy a 150W 12A/10V switching lab power supply.
3. Connect #2 into #1, and #1 into the battery.

When it comes to cost, it'd be extremely hard to beat this, unless your time is worth nothing.

If I were to actually design such a supply for personal use - just for the enjoyment of the design process, I'd probably make it a buck-boost switcher with a discrete control loop using op-amps and some gates/analog switches. The programming input would be PWM - to be flexible in the update rate vs. resolution tradeoff. Two duty-cycle-to-voltage converters, each double integrators that alternate hold/charge functions, would convert PWM to reference voltages. Then a current-mode controller as an internal loop, voltage mode controller as the outside loop - nothing super fancy. The switching voltage controller would be set to 1V above the output. A single stage linear regulator would take care of the output voltage. In fixed-current operating mode, it would be in dropout, and that's fine.

There are of course many, many ways of doing this - especially if you would use integrated switching supply controllers.